# Textfield in Vaadin does not align text correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, vaadin

I know that IE version 9 is outdated, but the customer wants it that way..

Does anyone have a single clue why the text in a Textfield looks like this in Internet Explorer 9:
[image]

When I highlight the text, it aligns okay. I use the Valo theme and created the textfield as follows:

```
final TextField givenName = new TextField("Voornaam:");
givenName.setWidth("132px");
givenName.addStyleName("textfield");
givenName.setValue(value);
```

CSS:

```
.textfield{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked with your devtools, whats the difference between the focused and non-focused DOM looks like?

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to get the right selection. Especially in IE, that thing is awful when it comes to inspect elements

Comment: does this imply, that IE9 is the only browser showing this problem of all the browsers you have tested with?

Comment: Only IE9. Other browsers (Firefox & Chrome) have no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with Vaadin is adding following css-code:

```
.v-ie8 .textfield, .v-ie9 .textfield{   
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

The **.v-ie8** and .**v-ie9** specifies css code only for IE8 & IE9

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following rules to the css-textfield definition:

CSS:

```
.textfield{
    margin-left: 5px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but then the textbox is too large in the other browsers. I found another solution, will post it here